# Como puedo realizar Metodo de Multiplicacion Constante en PHP?

Tags: php

Este es el codigo que realice en PHP lo cual como funcion tiene realizar una tabla de Multiplicacion Constante en este caso parecida a la siguiente.
Igual cabe mencionar que primero encontre y realice este metodo en apache netbeans y como nunca he usado PHP lo intente implementar en este tipo de lenguaje de programacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que no hace las demas repeticiones como se muestra abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo a continuacion todo mi codigo hecho espero alguien lo pueda solucionar

```
`<?php
$veces = $_POST["Repeticiones"]; /*Rep*/
$n1 = $_POST["Semilla"];/*N1  Sem*/
$c1= $_POST["A"];/*C1 Cons*/
$multiplicacion=0;
$ctamano=0;
$ntamano=0;
$dato1="";
$dato2=""; 
$dato3=""; 
$nn=""; 
$sub=""; 
$newcua="";
$da1=NULL;
$da2=NULL;
$da3= NULL;
if ($n1 <= 999 && $c1 <= 999)
{
echo "Valor de Xo y Xi debe ser mayor a tres digitos";
}
else{

if ($veces <= 0)
{
echo "El numero de datos a generar no puede ser igual o menor a 0";
}
else{
 /*Condicion numero de repeticiones */
 /*Condicion A*Xi */
```

Apartir de aqui es donde realice mis condiciones para que haga toda la operacion de la multiplicacion constante

```
 for($i=0; $i<$veces; $i++)
  { 
 $multiplicacion=$n1*$c1;
 $cua=strval($multiplicacion);
 $ctamano = strlen($cua);
 $ntamano = strlen($n1);
 
 
  }

    if($ctamano%2 == 0)
    {
     $d1=($ctamano-$ntamano)/2;
     $d2=$d1+$ntamano;
     
     $nn=strval($multiplicacion);
     $sub=substr($nn,$d1,$d2 - $d1);
     $n1=intval($sub); 
    }

    
    else 
    {
    
    $newcua = '0'.$cua;
    $ctamano = strlen($newcua);
    // ----- cheka
    $d1 = ($ctamano-$ntamano)/2;
    $d2 = $d1 + $ntamano;
    $nn = $newcua;
    $sub = substr($nn,$d1,$d2 - $d1);
    $n1 = intval($sub);
    
    }

    /*Muestra el resultado de A*Xi (Yi)*/
    $da1 = array_fill(0,$veces,NULL);
    $da1[$i] = $nn;
    $dato1 = "y" .strval($i). ":  " .$da1[$i]. "\n";

    /*Muestra el resultado de (Xi)*/
    $da2 = array_fill(0,$veces,NULL);
    $da2[$i] = $sub;
    $dato2 = "x" .strval(($i + 1)). ":  " .$da2[$i]. "\n";

    /*Muestra el resultado de (Ri)*/
    $da3 = array_fill(0,$veces,NULL);
    $da3[$i] = "r" .strval($i). ":  0." .$sub;
    $dato3 = $da3[$i] . "\n";


   
    } 

    }
```

Aqui el codigo para que me muestre la tabla de las repeticiones ya con el resultado

```
      echo '<div id="formato" class="tab">';
      function CrearTabla (){
      echo '<div class ="tabla">';
      echo '<table id ="tablita">';
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $fila=1;


      }do{
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$dato1."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$dato2."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$dato3."</td>";

          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<br/>";

          $fila++;


          }while ($fila<=$veces);

          echo "<br/>";
          echo '</table>';
          echo '</div> </div>';


          ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entendí nada tu código, además cambias el nombre de las variables que lo hace aún más difícil de entender. Por ejemplo en las imágenes del algoritmo dices que la constante se llama `A` luego en el código pones que se llama `c1`, la semilla se llama `X` y en el código `n` y así sucesivamente

El algoritmo es simple de llevar a código, y tampoco hay mucho que explicar. En cada iteración se calcula A*X , Xi+1 y r.

```
<?php
$veces = 7; 
$X[] = 9803; //X0
$A= 6965;

echo '<table border=1"><thead><tr><td colspan="4">Izquierda</td><td>N° Pseudoalatoreo</td><tr><td>A</td><td>Semilla Xi</td><td>A*Xi</td><td>A(x+1)</td><td>ri</td><tr></thead><tbody>';
for($i=0; $i<$veces; $i++)
{
    $AX = $A * $X[$i]; 
    $X[] = intval(substr(str_pad($AX,8,0,STR_PAD_LEFT),2,-2)); //Xi+1
    $r = $X[$i+1]/10000;

    echo "<tr><td>{$A}</td><td>{$X[$i]}</td><td>$AX</td><td>{$X[$i+1]}</td><td>{$r}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";

?>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]